# Telerik RadDatePicker and RadTimePicker not open with WP 10

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, telerik, raddatepicker

I'm using Telerik UI for WindowsPhone 8 Q2 2015 version and my project is Universal app using 8.1 SDK.

My xaml:

```
<input:RadDatePicker  x:Name="MyRadDatePicker"/>
```

There are 3 step to reproduce this issues:

1. Tap to MyRadDatePicker to popup picker flyout.
2. Press hardware back button to close the picker flyout.
3. Do the #1 step and now i can't get the popup anymore.

Big issues :D

Anyone get this problem?
This is my question on Telerik forum:
http://www.telerik.com/forums/datepicker-and-timepicker-not-open-with-wp-10